# Why is a String in Haskell recognized as (wrong) type [Char]?

Tags: haskell

I have a function

```
mytest :: Int -> String
mytest = "Test"
```

ghci refuses to load the file:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Int -> String’
            with actual type ‘[Char]’
In the expression: "Test"
In an equation for ‘mytest’: mytest = "Test"
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Everything works once I add a wildcard operator:

```
mytest :: Int -> String
mytest _ = "Test"
```

Does anyone know why Haskell interprets the first `"Test"` as `[Char]` and the second one as `String`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`String` is just an alias for `[Char]`. It is defined like this:

```
type String = [Char]
```

A list of `Char` constitutes an `String`.

Your original function didn't work because the type checker is trying to match "Test" which is a `String` or `[Char]` data type with `Int -> String` type which results in a type error. You can make it work either by returning a function of `Int -> String` type:

```
mytest :: Int -> String
mytest = \x -> show x
```

which can be also written as:

```
mytest :: Int -> String
mytest x = show x
```

Or as you have done:

```
mytest :: Int -> String
mytest _ = "Test"  -- Return "Test" no matter what the input is
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the type system says: "I have a `[Char]` and that's not an `Int -> String` so I just throw an error." It doesn't even check whether `[Char]` would fit `String` because it already knows that it's not correct?

Comment: I tried `mytest = \x -> "Test"` and this works, too.

Comment: Or, `myTest = const "Test"`, since `const :: a -> b -> a`.

Comment: @Dominik What you are thinking is absolutely correct except the fact that `[Char]` and `String` are equivalent.

Comment: @Dominik `String` is just a different name for `[Char]`.

Comment: I know, that's why I was so confused when ghci said it was the wrong type.

Comment: @Dominik you can also write that function as `mytest = \_ -> "Test"` since you are not using the `x` anyway. :)

Comment: Ah. I didn't know I can also have lambda functions without variables. Cool. Thank you :-).

Comment: @Dominik it says it's wrong because `Int -> String` means a function that takes an int as argument, and returns a string. What the body of your code does, is just return a string without any argument. The type of `myTest` is `String` not `Int -> String`